# BsoD- Video TDR failure, Reason- atkmpag.sys

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, bsod, amd-radeon

It all started 5 days ago, when my sony vaio vpceb44en was working fine, but suddenly a BsoD occured, which is now more frequent. It shows a "Video TDR failure" and names atkmpag.sys in the last. The PC then restarts.

This again happens, mostly when it takes much processing (when the exhaust fan starts spinning like hell).

Also, the battery of laptop is dead, it was working on AC for almost 6 months, and because power cuts are not frequent here, I haven't thought of purchasing a battery. 
Although it is made to run for x64, I'm using x86, as it came with windows 7 x86 from the shop.

I upgraded to Win10 x86 because of those bsod's in hope to fix the problem, as I thought Win10 will install the compatible driver, but it's again happening. The driver is up yo date ( as it shows), but the bsods are still frequent. Also, after some bsod's, the laptop freezes, I mean not even the Vaio logo comes on restart, then I turn it off ( by pressing power button for 5 secs), and leave it for 15-20 mins, and then it boots as normal.

I don't know what is causing this, I've read the related post on SuperUser, but nothing came off, also, this issue is a little bit different. The problem mostly comes when using Google Chrome, but sometimes it happen when the laptop is idle too!

Also, the laptop is connected to an external monitor through VGA, as the screen's broken.

---

**Things tried**

1. Reinstalling graphics driver in safe mode.
2. Clean install to Windows 10
3. Updating the graphics driver to latest available.
4. Disabling the driver works, but the graphics turns sloppy, with the exhaust fan spinning  like hell(although I cleaned it), and then the laptop would become slow, and overheat, and ultimately turn off. But have never experienced BSOD after disabling the display adapter driver.

---

**Laptop specs-**

1. Model- Sony Vaio VPCEB44EN
2. OS- Win10 Home, 32bit
3. RAM- 2GB
4. GPU- AMD Radeon 5000 Mobility (as written on GPU-Z, on the sticker of laptop, it writes ATI Radeon inside, I'm assuming both are same)

---

Thanks, I've tried to make everything clear, but you can ask if u need some details, and please help me, have given almost 5 full days in researching for this problem.

---

GPU-Z Screenshot-
[image: http://gpuz.techpowerup.com/20/02/19/kbg.png]

---

In case you need details of driver, I'm attaching a screenshot of that too- [image: https://prnt.sc/r4icsh]

---

**UPDATE** I downloaded Who Crashed, and it's showing dxgkrnl.sys as culprit rather than atikmpag.sys that is seen on bsod! I'm attaching a screenshot

https://prnt.sc/r4xdlw

Comment: The fact that this happens when the machine gets hot (fans start spinning loudly) implies that this is a thermal issue, you may well need to open up the machine to clear out dust from the fans and possibly check or replace thermal compounds.

Comment: @Mokubai It does happen when the machine gets hot often, but not always.  It also sometimes happen when the laptop is idle, the fan not even making sound. I've opened and cleaned the laptop's fan, but it didn't work.

Comment: Do BSODs on both Windows 7 and 10 mention `atkmpag.sys` as the cause? You need a more precise identification of the video adapter - "AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series" is not enough to find the exact driver in https://www.amd.com/en/support. I assume your model is one of *Graphics > AMD Radeon HD > ATI Radeon HD 5000 Series*.

Comment: @harrymc Actually when in happened on windows 7, I didn't noticed much, as the blue screen there was full of details, I didn't read all of them (there were some codes like 0x0000016 and like that). But I remember that it caused due to graphics driver too, as after reboot it showed that "display driver has stopped responding and recovered". So I installed Win 10, and then I noticed the atikmpag.sys

Comment: @harrymc I know finding the driver is hard, as on AMD website, they have subcategories under the AMD mobility 5000 series, but that's all I can know, there's nothing written on Sony's website except the 5000 category. On the sticker, its just "ATI Radeon". I thought GPU-Z will help, but that's all it shows. If you can provide a compatible driver, I'll try it. [Have not tried replacing the atikmpag.sys files, as suggested on some sites, I  needed guidelines from a reputed forum]

Comment: The graphics drivers would likely have been replaced, reinstalled or upgraded to a newer version when Windows 10 was installed. This points to a hardware issue. Either your graphics chip is failing, or it is overheating which is causing it to fail intermittently.  Check and clear dust and gunk out your fans and heatsinks, replace thermal compounds if possible.

Comment: @Mokubai I too now think that it's a hardware failure, and I think I'll have to give it to the repair. But I'm still not understanding why it works fine on basic driver. And if it would be overheating problem, I just noticed that blue screen when the fan was not even spinning. And then the laptop was blank, I mean not even the Vaio logo came, so I couldn't even go to the BIOS. After 7-8 attempts of turning it on, it finally booted fine. If the graphics chip failed, how does the laptop works this long? Wasn't it supposed to turn off immediately?

Comment: **Update** I downloaded Who Crashed, and it's showing dxgkrnl.sys instead of atikmpag.sys. Does this mean something else?

Comment: Dxgkrnl would be the DirectX Graphics Kernel driver which talks to your graphics card to draw things. It is still firmly pointing at something being seriously wrong with your graphics card as, again, it would have been updated and/or reinstalled with the update.

Answer (score 1):

Your best would might be to use the Auto-detect software:

> **Auto-Detect and Install Radeon Graphics Drivers for Windows**
>   
>   For Radeon Graphics and Processors with Radeon Graphics Only

**These products have driver support for Windows 10 and DirectX 11**

> AMD Radeon HD 6000 Series/AMD Mobility Radeon HD 6000 Series Graphics
>   AMD Radeon HD 5000 Series/**AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series Graphics**
>   
>   If your graphics adapter is included on the list of supported products, please install the latest 
>   AMD Catalyst Driver for Windows 10 to fully enable its feature set.
>   
>   AMD Catalyst Driver can be downloaded from:
>   [www.amd.com/drivers.](http://www.amd.com/drivers)
>   
>   Source: [Windows 10 Driver Support for AMD Radeon Graphics Products](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-615)
>   
>   Best wishes.

Comment: Thanks for your support! I actually noticed an option "C3/C6 support" in my bios, I turned it off, and then started my laptop. The fan is almost on full speed, and the bsod is now less frequent, (it happened last time when I used chrome, it mostly happen when I connect it to internet). I'm not just making random assumption, but I don't think now that it's a hardware failure, as the fan is spinning now at almost full speed, and have not got bsod since past 1 hour. I'll surely try the Auto Detect software, and update this thread soon! Also, has internet something to do with it?

Comment: The next time you open Google's Chrome, check out the Task Manager and look at all the power Chrome is using, (CPU, Memory, etc.). This might be why your fans are running at full speed. Check out this page here (MacBook though) https://superuser.com/questions/1526798/ridiculous-number-of-google-chrome-helper-renderer-processes-created

Comment: Yeah I know Chrome eats much memory, but I can't find a link between the graphics problem and the internet. After disabling C3/C6 from bios, the fan spins even when idle, but not causing bsod. Although the bsod is random and had happened many times on different applications, but opening and using chrome a little bit is a sure way of causing it, I mean I can get the bsod on other apps too, but with chrome, its sure to happen. I'm not assuming it as the memory problem, as the fan spins violently w/o chrome too, but does not cause the bsod! Any reason for that?

Comment: Have you tried the graphics download (auto-detect) tool?

Comment: Have downloaded it, it extracted a folder with setup.exe. I clicked on setup.exe and it showed that this app can't run on your PC. Perhaps the tool is not made for 32bit.

Comment: @Aditya Shinha I have just downloaded it (approx 40MB), and ran it, I am using Windows 10 32-bit Pro. It ran on this. Maybe the downloader missed something? I also extracted it using 7-zip into a folder, you can view the contents inside, and ever run the .exe file Setup.exe from within the folder.

Comment: Okay I'm going to download it once again. Just an update that it has been 3 times from morning that the graphics has flickered but no bsod, it restored again within a second. Will update as soon as possible.

Comment: It didn't ran this time too. The extracted folder contains Bin64 folder, Config folder, and a setup.exe file which is not running. Is your downloaded file also named as "radeon-software-adrenaline-2020-20.2.1-minimalsetup-200203_web.exe" ? Just a cross check that I'm downloading correct thing or not!

Comment: Hey you told you extracted using 7zip, but my downloaded one is an .exe file, am I downloading the wrong thing?

Comment: 7-Zip can extract most .cab, .zip, .exe, etc. files.  Yes, that is the correct file. You should be able to see an icon of the .exe file. If you cannot see the icon something is wrong. But yes, that is the correct name of the file. I just right-clicked the [Download] box and chose "save link as..."

Comment: Well you know yesterday the user profile failed to login, and the recovery option didn't worked too, so I have to install a clean copy of Win 10 (Pro this time). I then downloaded a driver for AMD 5400, and disabled the "Update drivers with windows update option", and everything seems to work fine now, no bsod, even on full exhaust. Just now that the battery led is now blinking continuously, and the battery shows at 255%, but the bsod looks solved now.

Comment: Although I've to press the power button to turn on more than one time now, as the power light turns on and then off automatically, but still, if it's working in this state too, I'm happy! Will write this as answer after some days of cross checking!