# Ridiculous number of Google Chrome Helper (Renderer) processes created

Tags: google-chrome, macbook, macbook-air

I'm seeing a large number of Google Chrome Helper threads being generated on my new macbook air(see attached). This is killing my laptop's memory and is making Chrome almost unusable (tabs don't load, or it eventually crashes).

Chrome was installed on a brand new macbook air.

Corrective actions attempted: 
-All extensions were removed.
-Chrome was reset to default settings
-Flash was disabled by default
-Chrome was uninstalled/reinstalled
-Macbook air was reset multiple times

Has anyone found anything that reduces this process to an acceptable number?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtX65.png)

Comment: Chrome Version 80.0.3987.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Too many page, too much cache, too many add-ons, etc. pease see "Google Chrome Helper Mac Memory" https://www.greatopedia.com/2018/03/google-chrome-helper-mac-memory.html for a start. There is also an Apple at Stack Exchange "Google Chrome Helper Using Up Too Much Memory" where you might want to join in the community https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274647/google-chrome-helper-using-up-too-much-memory